# Can't understand return value of getche() C

Tags: c, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX 30
void main()
{
char str[MAX];
char str2[MAX];
int i=0;
char c2,c1;
printf("Inserire stringa 1:\n");
do
{
    c2=getche();
    if(c2<0)
    {
        c1=getche();
    }
    else
    {
        c1=c2;
    }
    str[i]=c1;
    i++;
}while(i<=MAX&&c1!='\n');

printf("\n");
i=0;
printf("Inserire stringa 2:\n");
do
{
    c2=getche();
    if(c2<0)
    {
        c1=getche();
    }
    else
    {
        c1=c2;
    }
    str2[i]=c1;
    i++;
}while(i<=MAX &&c1!='\n');
printf("\n");
```

}

I can't understand what this code does.Expecially the if cycle:when is c2<0?what does return getche function?
Also the while condition is giving me some problems:even if i press enter it doesn't esc fro the cycle and i just overwrite the first word until i don't write 20 chars.

Comment: the header file `conio.h` is not portable,  suggest using the functions from the C library

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.   Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  3) following the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: although the Visual Studio application allows the main() signature of `void main()`.  there are actually only two valid signatures: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Strongly suggest using one of the valid signatures,

Comment: a bit of horizontal spacing around operators and inside parens makes the code much easier to read

Comment: I don't know about the function: `getche()`, but `getchar()` always returns an `int` so the `EOF` event can be represented.

Comment: if the `c2` variable contains a value the is greater than 127, (I.E. negative) then how can we expect the next value from `stdin` to not be?   Unless, the user is deliberately entering values >127, in which case every second input character will be lost